# Regex, filter url ending with and without digit

Tags: python, regex, url, filter, uri

I have below four URLs, out of which I want to filter only two using regex expression.

`/chassis/motherboard/cpu`      <---- this

`/chassis/motherboard/cpu/core0`

`/chassis/motherboard/cpu0`     <---- this

`/chassis/motherboard/cpu1/core0`

I have tried to play around with `^.*[0-9a-z_].cpu` but I'm unable to get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^.*/cpu[0-9]*$
```

This will match any text that ends with `/cpu` or `/cpy<number>`